# Proof of the statement about Fourier transform

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

I have a problem proving the statement about Fourier transform

$$
\begin{align*}f(t) &= \int_{-b}^b  S(\nu)e^{2\pi i \nu t}d\nu\\ &= \int_{-b}^b  S(\nu)e^{2\pi i \nu t_0}e^{2\pi i \nu (t-t_0)}d\nu\\ &= 
\int_{-b}^b S(\nu) e^{2\pi i \nu t_0}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(2\pi i \nu (t-t_0))^n}{n!}d\nu \\ &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(2\pi i (t-t_0))^n}{n!}\int_{-b}^b \nu^n S(\nu)e^{2\pi i \nu t_0}d\nu\\ &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(t-t_0)^n}{n!} f^{(n)}(t_0)\end{align*}
$$

**Question:**
Why can we move the sum out of the integral?

Comment: @K: What is $f$? what is s(v)$?  Why (and when) the first equality hold? Do you know any theorem in measure theory in which the sum and integral are interchanged?

Comment: $f$ - Lebesgue integrable function ($\int |f|\,d\mu <+\infty$), $S(\nu)$ - the Fourier transform of $f$, first equality - inverse Fourier transform ($S(\nu)$ has a limited support). I know some theorems, but I struggle to apply one here.

Comment: This is essentially Fubini's theorem by considering the counting measure. Of course, you need assumptions on $S(\nu)$.

Comment: @Jack Thank you for the reply! Would you mind dropping a couple of lines in the reply, so I could accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, when one is doing [Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform), one has the integral on the real line; if one performs the integral on a compact interval, say $[-b,b]$ as in the post, then one is looking for the [Fourier series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series#Definition).

Regarding the exchange of the summation sign and integral sign, one can apply [Fubini-Tonelli theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini's_theorem#The_Fubini.E2.80.93Tonelli_theorem) by considering the counting measure. Of course, one needs assumptions on the function $S(\nu)$.

Comment: Could you please explain, what are the assumptions on the function $S(\nu)$ and which of three integrals in the definition of Fubini–Tonelli theorem (by your link) is applicable here?

Comment: One needs to specify what function space one is doing the Fourier transform; as for the Fubini-Tonelli, any one of the three integrals (in the *assumptions*) there being finite would work.

Comment: For example, the transform is in $L_1$ and I could say that $S(\nu)$ is in this space. However, how can I prove that the resulting expression under the integral is also finite?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm being dumb and missing something here, but the only term in the sum that is dependent on the integral is $ v $. It just seems that they took the $ v $ out of the sum and pulled the remaining part of the sum out of the integral, since it no longer depends on $ v $.

Is that it, or am I completely wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure that this reasoning is correct, because $\nu^n$ remains inside the integral and we have an infinite sum of integrals.